# application Support folder doesn't have iphone folder while creating a directory

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I am creating a directory using `Phonegap`. I am getting success while using code. But I need to check where my folder is created. I found link they told these link.

```
/Users/UserName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications 

/Users/loginname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/YOUR_APP/Documents
```

But I don't have any iPhone simulator folder in application support? Where I will search?

I have Xcode 4.5 version

How to find android directory using the same code .i am able to in Ios

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


      function onDeviceReady() {
          window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemFail);
      }

      function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
          console.log(fileSystem.name);
          var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
          directoryEntry.getDirectory("newDir", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail)
      }

      function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
        //alert("onSuccess")
          console.log(parent);
         // alert(parent+"Directory");
      }

      function onDirectoryFail(error) {
          alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
      }

      function onFileSystemFail(evt) {
          console.log(evt.target.error.code);
          alert(evt.target.error.code);
      }
```

Comment: This folder is hidden! open a finder then press command + Shift + G then paste your URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is just copy the url

Go to the finder and press `command + shift + G` and paste your url and `press Go`

You don't need to enable hidden file.

Comment: How to find directory on Android .?

Comment: @user2484319 you mean using `Phonegap`?

Comment: yes ..I make "newDir" in ios I check it is make ..But Now i want to check in android .

Comment: @user2484319 did you check the sample at Phonegap Docs

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're not searching for it because you will get the wrong application folder, you have to go to your "user name" folder and make it show hidden files and that will show the hidden library file so you can start navigating your way to that address... try that and anymore issues with it ill try and help further.

Comment: Yes i am going like that .my mac name is "abc" click to Macintosh HD -> Library->applicationfolder

Comment: well if youre going mac hd ->library thats the wrong library my friend... you have to go mac hd-> users-> "your name" -> then in here is the hidden library

Comment: How to find that hidden library ?

Comment: i go to mac hd-> users-> "abc" -> (desktop,documents,dounloads)

Comment: which line ..sorry first time i am using mac

Comment: I do like this but no effect

Answer (score 0):

if you dont know how to open terminal go to search magnifying glass top right corner, click it and in the finder search bar type in terminal and press enter. a terminal window will pop up and after you copy this line " defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE " copy that without the " " part. now right click "if you have a two buttton mouse " on that terminal window and click paste from the menu that pops up, now press enter.  now last thing is to close all finder windows so copy this " killall Finder " without quotes and paste that in terminal and press enter...now your hidden folders will come up in your finder windows and the new faded hidden librarry folder will be under mac/users/"whatever ur username is "/